# Multiline regex works online, not in PHP

Tags: php, regex

This specific pattern matches as I'm testing it on regex101, but not in my code.

```
/(?s)%if_something%.*%endif_something%/
```

The code in question:

```
$text = "abc
         %if_something%
         <p>Content to potentially remove</p>
         %endif_something%
         123";

$regex = "/(?s)%if_something%.*%endif_something%/"

preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
```

Expected behavior is to return.

```
"abc
123"
```

I suspect regex101 doesn't handle whitespace and line carriage the same as a PHP string, but even removing any whitespace from my PHP string, I still don't get a match.

Comment: what is left is `abc\n\n123`

Comment: @rock321987 right now, the complete string is left

Comment: check this :- http://ideone.com/PAIUJ6

Comment: You don't assign the `preg_replace` to anything. Isn't the result of the replace returned?

Comment: Oh god I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine. However there are some syntax issues and also that you don't save the returned value

```
$text=preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
^
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/553171)**

**Output**

```
abc

         123
```

Those blank spaces are there because they are there in your original string and you don't replace them with anything.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you aren't assigning the result of your replace to anything. If you wan't it to end up in $text, make sure to assign the result to it:

```
$text=preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
```

Regards